# Instaling SSL on apache2

Tags: apache, ssl, configuration, apache2, crt

I've obtained an SSL certificate from Comodo. I try to install it on an apache server using the following steps:

1. Upload to the directory `/home/perica` these files:

   `bedbids_com.crt`

   `bedbids_com.key`

   `bedbids_com.ca-bundle`
2. Edit  `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf` with

   ```
    SSLEngine on   
    SSLCertificateFile "/home/perica/bedbids_com.crt"    
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/home/perica/bedbids.key"    
    SSLCertificateChainFile  "/home/perica/bedbids_com.ca-bundle"
   ```

but at this point ssl is still not enabled. What do I miss?

Comment: 'Doesn't work' is not a problem description. Off topic.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the ssl module is enabled with:

```
sudo a2enmod ssl
```

(assuming you use a debian based linux distribution)

Then you should add to your configuration file something like:

```
NameVirtualHost [your IP address]:443
< VirtualHost [your IP address]:443>
       ServerSignature On
       SSLCertificateFile    /path/to/the/certificate/from/your/certificate/company/apache.crt
       SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/the/file/created/in/step/1.key [can be a .pem file too I think]
       SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/intermediate/cert.crt [optional, only if yout certificate compay provides you with one]
       SSLEngine On
</VirtualHost>
```

You will find detailled instructions here:
http://wiki.vpslink.com/Enable_SSL_on_Apache2